# Incompatible element type Id for collection of Account

Tags: error-messages, debugging, debug

I have this save error "Incompatible element type Id for collection of Account", and i don't know how to remove it. I've found many subject on Internet but nothing seems to correspond to my specific case.

I'm saving in 3 lists results from 3 SOQL requests. Then i'm trying to eliminate doublon searching by IDs. Here is my code :

```
    Set<Account> setAccount = new Set<Account>();        
    List<Account> newListAccount = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> newListAccountPhones = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> newListAccountEmails = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> myListAccount = new List<Account>();
String query = 'SELECT RecordType.Name,Origine_de_la_piste__c,SellerId__c,Id,Parent.Name,Name,FirstName__c,LastName__c,Phone,Email__c,Adresse_E_mail__c,CompanyName__c,N_Siren__c,SiretNumber__c,IntracomNumber__c,Iban__c,RIBBankAccountNumber__c,AccountOwner__c,BicSwift__c ,ParentId, Statut_CRM__c, Perimetre__c, Owner.Name, Sourceur__r.Name, (SELECT Email,Autre_adresse_e_mail__c, FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone FROM Contacts WHERE Email != NULL OR (Autre_adresse_e_mail__c != NULL) ) FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN :relIds AND (' + String.join(conditions, ' OR ') + ')';
        newListAccount = (Database.query(query));
        String query1 = 'SELECT RecordType.Name,Origine_de_la_piste__c,SellerId__c,Id,Parent.Name,Name,FirstName__c,LastName__c,Phone,Email__c,Adresse_E_mail__c,CompanyName__c,N_Siren__c,SiretNumber__c,IntracomNumber__c,Iban__c,RIBBankAccountNumber__c,AccountOwner__c,BicSwift__c ,ParentId, Statut_CRM__c, Perimetre__c, Owner.Name, Sourceur__r.Name, (SELECT Email,Autre_adresse_e_mail__c, FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone FROM Contacts WHERE Email != NULL OR (Autre_adresse_e_mail__c != NULL) ) FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN :relIds AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Phone IN :Phones)';           
        newListAccountPhones = (Database.query(query1));
        String query2 = 'SELECT RecordType.Name,Origine_de_la_piste__c,SellerId__c,Id,Parent.Name,Name,FirstName__c,LastName__c,Phone,Email__c,Adresse_E_mail__c,CompanyName__c,N_Siren__c,SiretNumber__c,IntracomNumber__c,Iban__c,RIBBankAccountNumber__c,AccountOwner__c,BicSwift__c ,ParentId, Statut_CRM__c, Perimetre__c, Owner.Name, Sourceur__r.Name, (SELECT Email,Autre_adresse_e_mail__c, FirstName, LastName, Phone, MobilePhone FROM Contacts WHERE Email != NULL OR (Autre_adresse_e_mail__c != NULL) ) FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN :relIds AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :Emails)';           
        newListAccountEmails = (Database.query(query2));

        myListAccount.addAll(newListAccount);
        myListAccount.addAll(newListAccountPhones);
        myListAccount.addAll(newListAccountEmails);

        for(Account myAcc : myListAccount){
            for(Id myId : myAcc.Id )
            {
                if(setAccount.contains(myId) ){

                }

                else{
                    setAccount.addAll(newListAccount);               
                }
            }

        }
```

if(setAccount.contains(myId) => this line is the problem, and i don't know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance for reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've `Set<Account>` so `setAccount.contains()` should be of `Account` type and not `Id`. Refer below example:

```
for(Account myAcc : myListAccount){
    if(setAccount.contains(myAcc) ){

    }
    else{
        setAccount.addAll(newListAccount);               
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, i needed 2 different Set to do my work thanks a lot for reply